# Unable to call a class using Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

If I do that :

```
from myapp import models
User.objects.first()
```

I got that error :

```
NameError : name 'User' is not defined
```

whereas if I do that

```
import myapp
myapp.models.User.objects.first()
```

it works

I don't understand at all why I have that problem

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
from myapp import models
```

with the following:

> This way, you are telling Django which model classes to import rather than leaving Django guessing what to do with it.

> It prevents you from loading unnecessary models which might not be used right away and could potentially increase load time.

```
from myapp.models import User
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your have not imported class `User` actually. You have imported it's module called `models`
You can do one of these:

```py
from myapp import models
models.User.objects.first()
```

Or:

```py
from myapp.models import User
User.objects.first()
```